# How can I increase Tps in Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: performance, google-cloud-platform, minecraft, packet

I'm running minecraft server(modded) using 4Ram with 32G.
It's stable when 1~2people, but when people join server, tps become low.
I think it is not a problem with rams. But packets are too many transfered client and server.
How can I increase tps?

Comment: You dont provide any details about anything - no config file details, no details where do you run the server (AppEngine? Something else?), so it's difficult to give you any advice about anything. Maybe try googling first and read some existing articles dedicated to this use-case. This guide is one of the first google results: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/gaming/minecraft-server

Comment: @Park Harry, just as a kind reminder take a look here stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

The primary causes of TPS drops are a result of what you have going on in your world.
When adding mods or plugins, you should be thinking about the long-term effects of your choices.

For each modded block you add that provides some type of function, the server has to allocate resources to ensure that function is carried out. Now on its own that one block is of little consequence. But if that block forms an array as is typically done with solar panels, then the server will need to dedicate more resources to carry out that arrays functions. When we break it down we can get an idea of how much is really going on in the background.

Minecraft does not have any built-in methods for checking the RAM usage, but you can check the RAM usage by installing the Essentials plugin and using the command “/memory”. You can take a look at this [link](https://www.bisecthosting.com/clients/knowledgebase/76/How-to-troubleshoot-and-reduce-lag.html) for more information. Also this command can help you to determine the Current TPS.
Additionally,  you will find some good recommendations the last link that may help you to resolve your problem:

> Reduce view distance
>
> Your Minecraft server will run at view distance of 10 by default. We recommend changing your view distance to 6, this will not make any noticeable difference to players, but this can hugely help your server performance. You can learn how to access your server settings [here](https://www.bisecthosting.com/clients/knowledgebase/14/How-to-access-your-serverandsharp039s-settings.html).

> Setup automated restarts
>
> Setting up automatic restarts can help your server run smoother by freeing up your server RAM usage. It can also reclaim RAM that gets used by plugins and mods that have small memory leaks. You can view a tutorial on how to setup automated restarts [here](https://www.bisecthosting.com/clients/knowledgebase/21/How-to-schedule-automated-restarts.html).

> Run the latest version
>
> We recommend using the latest version of Minecraft, plugins, and mods on your server. Most newer versions of software will include bug fixes and performance improvements that will make your server run faster and more stable.

> Remove unnecessary mods and plugins
>
> Having unused plugins and mods on the server will use up server resources even if the plugins and mods are not being used. It is a good idea to remove any unnecessary mods and plugins from the server. If you think you may use some plugins in the future and are not using right now, you can disable plugins by renaming the plugin .jar file to end with “.disable.” E.g Essentials.jar.disable. You can remove “.disable” from the plugin name to enable the plugin again.

I also found this [documentation](https://cubedhost.com/help/en/articles/3076473-how-do-i-optimize-my-server-s-performance) that explains, How to optimize the server's performance? That may help you to troubleshoot your issue.

On the other hand, I recommend you to review the following guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to provide a better context on what you are doing and what you want to achieve.